# install jquery via grunt with bootstrap workflow

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, gruntjs

I'm trying to set up a new work flow, and watched some tutorials on Grunt, Compass and SASS. I got bootstrap downloaded and plugged into my project. I noticed that the jQuery library didn't download with it, or at least I can't seem to find it, and the burger menu for bootstrap doesn't seem to be working. Did I miss something or do I need to have Grunt install jQuery for me? I would assume I would put it into my gruntfile.js. Not sure if I would have to require it in the config.rb file? I also added the bootstrap.min.js file to the dev js folder. Do I just download the jQuery file ad add it to that folder. I was hoping to keep using the CDN version. Any help or a point in the right direction would be great. I've tried a few things and while I don't get any console errors, the menu doesn't work, which usually means the jQuery isn't installed.

Here are the files I mentioned:
package.json

```
{
"name" : "rouxmeetups",
"version" : "0.0.1",
"dependencies" : {
    "grunt" : "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch" : "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-compass" : "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify" : "~0.2.2",
    "matchdep" : "~0.1.2",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "3.2.0",
}
```

}

gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bootstrap');
grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
        my_target:{
            files:{
                '_/js/script.js' : ['_/components/js/*.js']
            } // files
        } // my_target
    },// uglify
    compass: {
        dev: {
            options:{
                config: 'config.rb'
            } // options
        } // dev
    }, // compass
    bootstrap: {
        dev: {
            options:{
                config: 'config.rb'
            } // options
        } // dev
    }, // bootstrap
    watch:{
        options: {
             livereload: true
        }, // options
        scripts:{
            files: ['_/components/js/*.js'],
            tasks: ['uglify']
        }, // scripts
        sass: {
            files: ['_/components/sass/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['compass:dev']
        }, //sass
        html:{
            files: ['*.html']
        } // html       
    } // watch
}) // initConfig
grunt.registerTask('default', 'watch'); // set to be the default task for grunt
```

}

config.rb

```
require 'bootstrap-sass'

css_dir = '_/css'
sass_dir = '_/components/sass'
javascript_dir = '_/js'
output_style = :compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [bower](http://bower.io/) to handle front-side dependencies and npm only for node-js environment dependencies (your dev tools).

Then you'll need a bower.json (same as package.json) where you'll refer to  bootstrap lib (bootstrap should auto-download jquery as it's one of its dependencies).

Another thing, I suggest you to use [grunt-libsass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) instead of `grunt-contrib-compass` which is much much faster and ruby-free.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have been reading up on libsass, seems like everyone is very impressed with the performance of it!